# Remove a href tag conditional from php string

Tags: php, regex

I have a srting like this.

```
$str = "this is a bet and he is <a href=''>Mansoon</a> and he please search on <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and say he <a href=''>Yammy</a>";
```

I want to remove all a href tags from string with blank href. Can you please loook into this.

Output like this

```
$str = "this is a bet and he is Mansoon and he please search on <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and say he Yammy";
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried?

Comment: use this regex `<a href=''>[^<>]*<\/a>` and replace the match with empty string.

Comment: you can use regex to search for `<a href='` (delete everything untill next `'`).

Comment: @AvinashRaj - <a href=''>[^<>]*<\/a> this will not work if href= ""(having double quote)

Comment: then it would be `<a href=(['"])\1>[^<>]*<\/a>`

Answer (score 4):

**try this:**
**Update**
*it may full fill all exception cases :*

```
$re = "/(<a[^href]*href=[\"']{2}[^>]*>)([^<>]*|.*)(<\\/a>)/m";
$str = "this is a bet and he is <a id=\"sss\" href='' dfsd fdg >Mansoon</a> and he please search on <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and say he <a href=''>Yammy</a> \n<a href=''> <i>Yammy </i> <br/> </a>\n\nthis is a bet and he is Mansoon and he please search on <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and say he Yammy";
$subst = "$2";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/pQ3pN9/4)**

Comment: Except: `href='"` or `<a href=''><i>Yammy</i></a>` or other html in the `href`.

Comment: `[^<>]*|.*` is the same as `.*`

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression  will works for you

```
<a[^>]*herf='*'[^>]*>[^>](.*?)<\/a> //works well even after space anywhere
```

Comment: Lalit but how can i keep Mansoon or etc. like explained in question . I can replace this with blank or particular string

Comment: @bhupendra - not able to past here doing modification in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This `<a\h+href=(['"])\1>([^<>]*)<\/a>` regex would match all the anchor tags which has an empty  `href` value. Replacing the matched `<a>` tags with `$2` will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mZ7nJ3/2)

```
<?php
$str = "this is a bet and he is <a href=''>Mansoon</a> and he please search on <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and say he <a href=''>Yammy</a>";
echo preg_replace('~<a\h+href=([\'"])\1>([^<>]*)<\/a>~', '$2', $str);
?>
```

Output:

```
this is a bet and he is Mansoon and he please search on <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and say he Yammy
```

`\h+` matches one or more horizontal whitespace characters.

Comment: this will not work if there is a white space like <a ***** href="">sdfsfs     </a>

Comment: now, it won't. Is there any possibility of one or more white space before `href` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$str = "this is a bet and he is <a href=''>Mansoon</a> and he please search on <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> and say he <a href=''>Yammy</a>";
$pattern = '/<a[^>]*?href=(?:\'\'|"")[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/a>/i';
$replacement = '$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Test [regex: here](http://regex101.com/r/wU3lZ5/1)